# Unit test that checks usage of resources

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resources

I have a huge solution with a lot of projects in it. and i have a resource file that contains a string resources. I need a unit test that will check that each and every string-resource from resource file is used somewhere in code of solution.
My idea is to 1) parse resource file as a xml file and get ID of each particular resource string from it 2) parse all source code files as simple text file and look up there this ID. if it is present somewhere it means that this string-resource is used in code.

But here come a problem: how to determinate from unit test a directory where code is? (it can be in different places i cant hard-code it)

what would you suggest? is there another way to check usability of each and every resource?
if not, how to get a directory where code is from unit test?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe I've just misunderstood you, but unit testing wasn't meant for this. It's meant to check the functionality of individual units, not to do fulltext search for used resources...

Comment: Yes, you're perfectly correct. to check a usage of resources is not a straight purpose of unit test. but i do need this ))

Comment: Not only "not a straight purpose", but it's almost the opposite of unit testing... Unit test should NEVER be that long as you would need this one to be. Why do you want to include this into your unit testing?

Comment: cause im not the only one whos working with this project. and sometimes people adding resources in resource file but not using them in code, or deleting code that uses resource but not deleting resource from file. i need something that will tell them about it. fail of unit test will be great reason to review just written code.

Comment: I agree with @walther, this seems more like a job for static code analysis tools (like FxCop etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can try embedding this in your app somewhere:

```
string currentFile=new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
```

BTW: I hate it when people get pedantic about what "Unit tests" should or should not do. If it's a useful test, go for it.